# Is it possible to connect MongoDB to React directly?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, api

I have a small react component that lists data from a gist api

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "(the gist URL)";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const api_data = await response.json();
    this.setState({data: api_data})
    console.log(api_data)
  }
```

I would like to know how I can pull the same data from a mongodb without having to use express.

Comment: Nop.. not recommended. If you need to do that that would be a serious security issue. Either your db has to be open or you the credentials will be exposed.  So if you are not interested in building any server for yourself you can try some pre-built ones from https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/use-cases/http-interfaces

Comment: It's not recommended to connect directly to MongoDB as @Panther mentioned. However there are solutions that offer client side MongoDB compatible interface which can sync to MongoDB. Check out [minimongo](https://www.mongodb.com/realm) and [MongoDB Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/realm)